# How to access `/scratch` directory of nodes 2 to N in SLURM when node 1 doesn't have access to it?

Tags: slurm

I'm running a SLURM job with several nodes, where the nodes are arranged in the order of `1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... N`. However, I'm facing an issue where the `node 1` doesn't have access to the `/scratch` directory, while `nodes` `2` to `N` do have access to it.

I need to access the `/scratch` directory of nodes `2` to `N` or at least the /scratch directory of node 2 from the SBATCH script. However, whenever I send the job, node 1 is always the head node and I can only access the directories that are accessible from node 1.

I want to know how I can access the /scratch directory of `nodes` `2` to `N` from the `SBATCH` script. Please note that I only need to access the `/scratch` directory of one node and I don't need to share it among all nodes. Furthermore, I don't have access to SLURM config, so I can't change weights of the nodes, and administrator is not accessible at the time.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried adding`—nodelist=node2,node3,…,nodeN` to your sbatch command line or set the parameter in the script? (The option should have two single dashes but they get changed to — in my comment)

Comment: @doneal24 I get the same results, most probably SLURM sorts internally
I get:
`SLURM_NODELIST=node1,node2,...,nodeN`
`SLURMD_NODENAME=node1`,
`SLURM_TOPOLOGY_ADDR=node1`

Comment: Your admin has done something strange. Slurm does not sort nodes and a node name is tied to a single physical server. I believe the slurm config file has to be world-readable so you should be able to access it. Does `slurmd -C` give any useful info?

Comment: If you are out of other options you could try an `sshfs` mount of node2:/scratch onto node 1. You’ll need ssh access to the node using key authentication and performance will not be great.

Comment: What you mean is that node 1 is always the node to which your jobs are sent. The head node is the node that runs the scheduler for determining when and were jobs are sent in regards to the compute nodes. Without knowing what the Slurm configuration is, there is no way to determine why your jobs are always being sent to that particular node. The only thing that you can do is to wait until the engineer or admin of the cluster is available in order to determine what is going on or to find someone else who can do so.